# print dynamic scope value in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a loop like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat="z in cat"  ng-init="gettot(z.cats)">
   {{'one'+z.cats}}
</tr>
```

AM getting like one1 if z.cats=1.
AM expecting 'y' here.

In my controller , i have function

```
$scope.gettot =function(a){
 $scope['one'+a]='y';
}
```

My issue is, i need to print this value.
if a is 1, then i need to print like `{{one1}}`. But in dynamic situation, how can i do it..
i have tried like `{{'one'+z.cats}}`.
Am getting the output like  one1 rather than 'y'.  Please help me...

Comment: what do you want to do

Comment: i need to show  the value.. {{'one'+z.cats}}

Comment: you cannot do that, explain the requirement clearlu